# Row level security(RLS) performance is significantly slower in postgres.

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance, database-indexes, row-level-security

Description :
Here is the sample demonstration of the performance issue.

We first created two tables  , enabled row level security and created policy as well .

Table definition:

```
create table sample_schema.sample_table1(ID numeric(38) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                 tenant_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                 Description VARCHAR(255)
        );

create table sample_schema.sample_table2(ID2 numeric(38) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                 tenant_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                 table1_id numeric (38),
                 Description2 VARCHAR(255)
        );
```

Index creation:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sample_table1_idx1 ON sample_schema.sample_table1(tenant_id,id);
```

Enable row level security:

```
ALTER TABLE sample_schema.sample_table1 ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

create role:

```
CREATE ROLE tenant_grp_role_p_id;
```

Create policy:I want a policy to select data where tenant_id column value has a  role that is same as the user who has logged in.

```
CREATE POLICY Tenant_Roles ON  sample_schema.sample_table1 TO tenant_grp_role_p_id USING ((tenant_id) IN ( SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE    pg_has_role( current_user, oid, 'member')));
```

create sample data:

```
insert into sample_schema.sample_table1 values (1,'user1_tenant1',1,'Table1 Data');
insert into sample_schema.sample_table2 values (2,'user1_tenant1',1,'Table2 Data');
```

Problem:below query is not using primary_key index .

```
SELECT * FROM sample_schema.sample_table1 ST1,  sample_schema.sample_table2 T2 WHERE ST1.id = ST2.table1_id  AND ST1.id = 1;
```

Question:If I disable RLS then primary key index is used .why is it not using primary key index scan when RLS is enabled?

Note :
A.If I disable the row level security and  run the above query  ,it uses the index.
B.below is the explain plan Output when low level security is disabled .

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..19.19 rows=1 width=1129)  ->  Index Scan using sample_table1_pkey on sample_table1 st1  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=37)
    Index Cond: (id = '1'::numeric)  ->  Seq Scan on sample_table2 st2  (cost=0.00..10.88 rows=1 width=1092)        Filter: (table1_id = '1'::numeric);
```

C.if I enable the low level security and run the query it does not use index.
and below is the explain plan Output when low level security is enabled.

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=1.03..946.65 rows=79 width=1129) ->  Seq Scan on sample_table2 st2  (cost=0.00..10.88 rows=1 width=1092)  Filter: (table1_id = '1'::numeric)  ->  Subquery Scan on st1  (cost=1.03..934.98 rows=79 width=37)
    Filter: (st1.id = '1'::numeric)        ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.03..738.11 rows=15750 width=37)              Hash Cond: ((st1_1.tenant_id)::name = pg_authid.rolname)              ->  Seq Scan on sample_table1 st1_1  (cost=0.00..578.00 rows=31500 width=37)              ->  Hash  (cost=1.01..1.01 rows=1 width=68)                    ->  Seq Scan on pg_authid  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=68)                          Filter: pg_has_role("current_user"(), oid, 'member'::text);
```

Please help me resolve this issue ..

Comment: Please preserve the formatting and indention of the execution plans. The way you added them to your question makes them useless.

Comment: This is the same as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169479/postgresql-multi-tenant-mode-not-using-index#comment69569639_41169479

Answer (score 15):

See [this message thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/103877619.228905.1477674957518.JavaMail.root%40trustedconcepts.com) on the pgsql-general mailing list for details.

> I recently applied RLS to several large (several million rows) tables
>   in my 9.5 database and noticed that queries against a single large RLS
>   protected table perform well however queries that join several large
>   RLS protected tables perform very poorly.  The explain plan shows the
>   optimizer is scanning the entire table to enforce the RLS policy
>   before executing the primary key join that would reduce the query
>   results to a single row from each table.  Clearly performance would be
>   better if it performed the join before the policy check.
>
> From what I can understand the RLS implementation strives to execute
>   policy checks before user provided predicate checks so as to avoid
>   leaking protected data.

And the responses:

> Join cases with RLS aren't optimized very well at the moment.  There's
>   work afoot to improve this - see
>   https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/8185.1477432701%40sss.pgh.pa.us
>   - but it won't be in production before v10.

And:

> You can use a security barrier view which is owned by the same user
>   that the tables underneath are owned by, that will bypass RLS on the
>   tables themselves and therefore you'll need to implement the
>   appropriate quals in the security barrier view.

So you could wait for PG10, or try using a [security barrier view](http://rhaas.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/security-barrier-views.html) instead. That blog post also explains why Postgres doesn't try to combine (and optimise) the security conditions and the user-specified conditions: a custom function can be used to leak values that would otherwise be hidden from the user.

To create such a view, just add `with (security_barrier)` to the definition:

```
rhaas=# create or replace view unclassified_emp with (security_barrier) as
        select * from emp where organization <> 'CIA';
CREATE VIEW
```

There's more information in [this detailed blog post](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/how-do-postgresql-security_barrier-views-work/) too.

Comment: With PG 10 the improvements mentioned in the referenced messages are now live: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/215b43cdc8d6b4a1700886a39df1ee735cb0274d

Comment: I had similar problem. Upgrading to postgres 10 makes significant difference.